# Xdebug not stopping on breakpoints in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I followed the Xdebug installation instructions and downloaded the php8.1VS16TS(64bit) file and copied it to `php8.1.0/ext` and renamed it to `php.xdebug.dll`.  I configured php.ini and NetBeans, and installed the Xdebug Helper for Firefox.  I can set breakpoints in the PHP code, but when debugging the application, the code never stops on a breakpoint.

I'm running

- Windows 10,
- Apache NetBeans IDE 12.6,
- Java 17.0.2,
- WAMP64,
- Apache 2.4.51,
- PHP 8.1.0,
- MySQL 5.7.36.

The `apache2.4.51/bin/php.ini` includes:

```ini
[opache]
 zend_extension = xdebug
[xdebug]
 xdebug.mode=debug
 xdebug.output_dir = "c:/wamp64/tmp"
 xdebug.show_local_vars=0
 xdebug.log="c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log"
 xdebug.log_level = 10
 xdebug.client_host=localhost
 xdebug.client_port=9003
 xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
 xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

In NetBeans > Tools > Options > PHP > Debugging:

```
 Debugger Port: 9003
 Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
 Maximum Data Length: 2048
 Stop on First Line is checked
 Resolve breakpoints is checked
```

When I debug the project in Firefox, I make sure the helper icon is green, but still no stopping on a breakpoint.

Not sure what else to do.  Any help is much appreciated - being able to step through the project would be a great help.

Here are the screen shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is in `c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log` ?

Comment: It was created by the WAMP installation.  I guess it's for future logging of xdebug events.

Comment: I didn't ask what it was, but what is was in it.

Comment: Sorry, it is empty.

Comment: @Ron It cannot be empty with the settings you have posted. Delete the log file and try again. If it's empty then Xdebug does not even try to debug or does not have enough permissions to write to that file... **I suggest doing this for now:** 1) make a new PHP file (or edit some existing one that you can call in your website) 2) call `xdebug_info();` in that file 3) post the screenshot of the whole page with the output (make a few images if needed). It will show your actual live settings.

Comment: @Ron Accordingly to the screenshot there is no service listening on TCP 9003 port. Could be Firewall issue or NetBeans is not in the listening mode (not ready to accept debug connections). Check that with `netstat` program -- check what apps listen on TCP 9003 port.

Comment: I ran netstat -o and got several lines with 9003 in them.  All were attached to TCP 192.168.1.65 which according to the PID is netbeans64.exe.  The UAC Virtualization is Disabled.  I also ran netstat with the -a and -an options but didn't get any more information, except the 192.168.1.65 was marked a DESK-TOP-E092TBF:0 Listening.  Not sure what all this means, but hope you'll know. The Windows firewall allows NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Then set `xdebug.client_host=192.168.1.65` and restart the web server/WAMP.